# How to implement a doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

We learned how to implement singly linked list in class.  And our professor kind of mentioned us doing doubly linked list, but apparently its so easy that he really didn't explain how to do it in full detail.  I'm really good at with working with singly linked list, but could someone tell me how to make a doubly linked list?

Comment: did you try google? There must be tons of tutorials on that..

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Or at least your implementation for a singly linked listed and how you think it could be changed.

Comment: Ask your professor; isn't that why you're in the class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already have a sound definition of a singly linked list, then a doubly linked list is easy.

Before you probably had something like

```
struct link{
  struct link* next; //a pointer to the node that comes next
  int value;
}
```

This will need to change to

```
struct link{
  struct link* next; //a pointer to the node that comes next
  struct link* prev; //a pointer to the node that comes before
  int value;
}
```

Now you can basically do your operations in reverse by using previous instead of next when traversing the list.

Keep in mind you need to be careful with your 'book keeping' to keep things pointed at the right things when adding or removing.

I always tell students to draw every step of adding and removing from a linked list when writing functions. And to always make sure that you keep a reference to everything in your drawing via a pointer somewhere until it is deleted.

Answer (score 3):

@kratenko has a great point, but for ease of access here is a short description.

Your singly linked list has pointers moving in one direction:

HEAD*-> |data| -> |data| -> |data| -> null

For a doubly linked list, implement a singly linked list in both directions:

HEAD* <-> |data| <-> |data| <-> |data| <-> TAIL*

where HEAD* and TAIL* are both nodes that have node* members pointing to them (inside the DoublyLinkedList class).

Answer (score 0):

You should add "dummy nodes" to the head and tail. This will simplify yor add and delete methods (you won't have to consider add and delete to/from the head and tail, you will just think the "middle situation").

Before conclusing the program, don't forget to replace your dummy nodes with NULL.